# X Error of failed request: BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation) when trying to output new mode

Tags: ubuntu, screen-resolution, xrandr

**Issue**:

Want to add a new resolution (2560X1440) to the external monitor (Lenovo ThinkVision E27q-20 27).
The highest resolution available is 1920X1080.
Getting an error when trying to output new mode that was added.

**Steps taken**:

1. Verified that the desired resolution is supported using the following command:

   cvt 2560 1440

   2560x1440 59.96 Hz (CVT 3.69M9) hsync: 89.52 kHz; pclk: 312.25 MHz
   Modeline "2560x1440_60.00"  312.25  2560 2752 3024 3488  1440 1443 1448 1493 -hsync +vsync
2. Added a new mode using the xrandr command and it is reflected in the xrandr list.

   Screen 0: minimum 16 x 16, current 1920 x 1200, maximum 32767 x
   32767
   XWAYLAND0 connected primary 1920x1200+0+0 (normal left inverted
   right x axis y axis) 600mm x 340mm
   1920x1200     59.88
   1600x1200     59.87
   1440x1080     59.87
   1400x1050     59.86
   1280x1024     59.76
   1280x960      59.94
   1152x864      59.78
   1024x768      59.68
   800x600       59.86
   640x480       59.38
   320x240       59.52
   1680x1050     59.85
   1440x900      59.89
   1280x800      59.81
   720x480       59.71
   640x400       59.20
   320x200       58.96
   1920x1080     59.88
   1600x900      59.82
   1368x768      59.88
   1280x720      59.86
   1024x576      59.90
   864x486       59.45
   720x400       59.55
   640x350       59.77
   2560x1440_60.00  59.96
   2560x1440_50.00  49.96

**Error**:

When trying to output the new mode using the command below, the following error occurs:

```
xrandr --output XWAYLAND0 --mode 2560x1440_60.00
Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of 
range for operation)
Major opcode of failed request:  139 (RANDR)
Minor opcode of failed request:  21 (RRSetCrtcConfig)
Value in failed request:  0x0
Serial number of failed request:  22
Current serial number in output stream:  22
```

what am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

This error is low level and in most case is related to hardware thing, one of this tips should solve your problem:

1. Check the connection of your display cable (HDMI, VGA, etc...).
2. Try another cable with better quality.
3. Check your graphic driver that was updated to last version.
4. Try lower resolution.
5. Try another monitor. :D